# Bash Script To Get HTML Table Data

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sed, grep

I have a web page that has a very simple HTML table. The HTML code of the webpage is as below. The HTML will always remain same, only the data values will change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Demo Page Results</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">
      </head>
      <body id="particles">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Demo Page Results</h1>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Examiner:
                </td>
                <td class="marked">
                  Person
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>
                  Qualification:
                </td>
                <td class="marked">
                  Teacher
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Nation:
                </td>
                <td class="marked">
                  Any
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>

          </div>

        <script src="/static/jrf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/scripts.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The output of the code is as below

## Demo Page Results

Examiner: Person

Qualification: Teacher

Nation: Any

I need to use bash scripting to get the contents of the table as follows

```
Examiner: Person

Qualification: Teacher

Nation: Any
```

I am using the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# URL of the webpage
# containing the HTML
# table
URL="http://thewebpageurl"
# Use curl to fetch the
# HTML content of the
# webpage
HTML=$(curl -s "$URL")
#echo $HTML
# Use grep and sed to
# extract the table
# content
TABLE_HTML=$(echo "$HTML" | grep -o '\<table\[^\>\]\*\>.\*\</table\>' | sed 's/\<\\/table.\*//')
echo $TABLE_HTML
# Use awk to parse and
# print the table data
echo "$TABLE_HTML" | awk -F"\</tr\>" '{ for (i=1; i\<=NF;i++) { sub(/.\*\<td\[^\>\]\*\>/, "", $i); sub(/\<\\/td\>.\*/, "", $i); printf "%s ", $i; } printf "\\n"; }'
```

But sadly this is not showing any results.

Kindly help and guide me to fix the bash script.
Thanks
Neha

Comment: For parsing HTML, I would suggest to use a proper programming language, with a good HTML parser library. Bash is not really suited for this; though there may be some good generic command line tool to parse HTML, not sure about that.

Comment: `awk` processes an input file line by line (or more specifically, record by record, where you can define your record separator). You don't know the line structure with the HTML file. For instance the same page could be written as a single, long line holding all the HTML code. awk is for sure unsuitable for this task. I would google here for _HTML parser_.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML code you want to process is always formatted in the same way, i.e. one tag per line and values as separate lines in all code related to the table? What about HTML entities, e.g. `&amp;` or `&#38;` to display a `&` character? Please [edit] your question to clarify this. Maybe `lynx --dump input.html | fgrep :`?

Comment: The obligatory [You. Can't. Parse. HTML. With. A. REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/298607)

Comment: How to process line by line using awk ? Kindly guide

Comment: Depending on whether `$HTML` is a multiline string, grep is going to look for your regex on one line at a time unless you use `grep -z`. (-z is GNU-only, not POSIX.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xmllint` in HTML mode and an XPath expression to extract the contents of the table cells, and then massage it into the desired format:

```bash
$ xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@class="container"]/table/tr/td/text()' input.html | perl -0777 -pe 's/:\s+/: /g; s/^\s+//mg'
Examiner: Person
Qualification: Teacher
Nation: Any
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a great XML/HTML parser available called [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/index.html).

You can do something like this:

```
ruby -r nokogiri -e 'Nokogiri::HTML($<.read).at("table").search("tr").
each{ |tr|
    cells = tr.search("th, td")
    puts cells.map{|cell| cell.text.strip }.join(" ")
}' file
```

Prints:

```
Examiner: Person
Qualification: Teacher
Nation: Any
```

Comment: Just to add the structure of the HTML code will never change, only the data values will change. Also kindly help me to achieve the required output by using only curl, grep, awk/sed.

Comment: With some hit and try... I got the bash curl -s http://myurl | awk '/<table>/,/<\/table>/' |   sed -n '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/p' |   sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | tr -d ' \n' but the output is a single line with all table data values I.e. Examiner:PersonQualification:TeacherNation:Any How do I add a # after each row? Eg Examiner:Person#Qualification:Teacher#Nation:Any

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML format will never change, as you stated, then using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
    $0 == "</td>"                   { inTag=inVal=0 }
    inTag { tag = $0 }
    inVal { print tag, $0 }
    $0 == "<td>"                    { inTag=1 }
    $0 == "<td class=\"marked\">"   { inVal=1 }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
Examiner: Person
Qualification: Teacher
Nation: Any
```

If you REALLY want a blank line after each output line as shown in the expected output in your question then just change `print tag, $0` to `print tag, $0 ORS`.

Comment: Thanks alot the code worked perfectly. What do I have to change to get the output in a single line as Examiner:Person#Qualification:Teacher#Nation:Any

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '!/^$|</{i++; printf "%s %s", $1, (i%2==0 ? "\n": "")}' file
Examiner: Person 
Qualification: Teacher
Nation: Any
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (xidel version 0.9.8, GNU paste and sed):

```
xidel file -se '//td' | paste -d' ' - -
```

or to put all on one line separated by `#`:

```
xidel file -se '//td' | sed 'N;s/\n//' | paste -sd#
```

---

The above solutions can also be replicated entirely with xidel (thanks to Reino) as:

```
xidel file -se '//tr/normalize-space()'
```

and:

```
xidel file -se 'replace(join(//tr/normalize-space(),"#")," ","")'
```

Comment: No need for other tools: `-e '//tr/normalize-space(td)'`. And besides, your solution doesn't produce the OP's desired result.

Comment: @Reino thanks but this does not reproduce the OPs desired result either. However `-e '//tr/normalize-space()'` does equate to my first solution. My second was in response to the first comment the OP made to Ed Morton's solution which with a little tinkering can be reproduced using `-e 'replace(join(//tr/normalize-space(),"#")," ","")'`

Comment: I'm getting very different results with `paste` and `sed`, but they're probably not up-to-date. If you however don't get the same result with `//tr/normalize-space(td)` **and** `//tr/normalize-space()`, then your `xidel` binary [isn't](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/) [up-to-date](https://nightly.link/benibela/xidel/workflows/main/master). Furthermore, if you wish to remove all white-space, then you can ditch `normalize-space()` entirely: `-e 'join(//tr/replace(td,"\s+",""),"#")'`